# How to change a color radially?

Tags: animation, color

I have lots of red dots on a sphere and I would like them to change to blue starting from one dot in the middle and then spreading outwards. Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried playing with the mapping values assigned to a color gradient but that doesn't seem to work properly. Any ideas?

Comment: hello, your question is much too vague, what do you call dot? Is the color supposed to spread from top to bottom of from inside to outside? Could you please show an image of your topology?